# Single vs multiple blog tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a classic php blog and have a dilemma about `single` or two mysql tables approach.

In the first case actual blogs would be placed inside `actual` table (100 rows max), and archived posts inside `archive` table (20.000 rows max).

Both tables have the same structure.

Querying on `actual` table is very often and on `archive` is not so often.

But sometimes there are `join` and `union` queries - covering both tables.

Logically, performances are much better on a smaller table but  - is that in my case  enough reason to create two tables instead single one?

There is also third solution - single table with two partitions `actual - 100 rows`and `archive - 20.000 rows`.

What to do?

Comment: could you have an archive field, and instead of moving to a different table when archiving, instead just mark the entry as archived, and only query rows not marked as archived?

Comment: Add achieve field instead of creating table with same structure

Comment: @JamesLingham, yes I can do that, of course.

Comment: @NadeemShaikh, would that make my queries slower?

Comment: @blueSky That would be my suggestion - but im not really an expert in this kind of thing, it may be worth seeing what other people have to say.

Is there a particular reason you would want to avoid something like this?

Comment: @JamesLingham, I understand, thanks a lot.

Comment: Having two tables with identical structure, but one for archiving and one for "live" records is pointless. Tables aren't like directories / folders. MySQL storage won't work the way you intuitively think it does. Have a single table, create a column `archived` with 1 and 0 for the status. Partitioning on such a tiny number of records will do what? Where will you partition it to? The same drive? What's the point then?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> Logically, performances are much better on a smaller table

With respect, your intuition about this is *entirely incorrect* for tables containing less than about ten million rows.  A purpose of SQL is to allow rapid retrieval of a few items from among many.  Thousands of years of programmer labor (not an exaggeration) have gone into making this kind of thing very fast. You won't be able to outsmart that collective effort.

Put your items in one table.  If you need to distinguish between active and inactive items, make a column called `active` or some such thing, and retrieve them with `WHERE active=1` or some such query term.

If you think you're having performance problems you can add indexes to your tables. Read this.  https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: thanks for your explanation. Btw, indexing vs partitioning - what is better regarding performances?

Comment: also, are you really sure that `where active = 1` on a `20.000` rows makes a query so fast that there is no a sigificant difference compared to `100` rows without that clause?

Comment: Partitioning only conceivably makes sense when you have 10^^8 or more rows. It's an enormous pain to configure and maintain, and all except carefully designed queries become very slow (because of indexing complexity). And, yes I'm sure properly indexed queries on twenty-kilorow tables are fast. Are they faster than queries on tiny tables? Probably, but any difference is at or below the millisecond level.  Measure the success of your project in posts per month (development and debugging time) rather than posts per microsecond (raw retrieval time).  Look up the acronyms KISS and YAGNI.

Comment: you probably mean `are they slower` instead of `are they faster`?

Answer (score 0):

While designing databases, don't only think about how you will store the data; but think about all the possible cases:

- How are you going to retrieve and update information?
- Will there be different views and different permissions for different
  people?

In your case, `archive` seems like a subset of `actual` table. So a single table would be preferred with a row for keeping track of archived files.

Comment: yes but this `subset` is about `20.000` rows and the  `main set` is `100` rows only.

Comment: Not a bother for any modern dbms. If the scale is in tens of millions, then you should start worrying.